# PHP curl doesn't work

Tags: php, curl

Hey guys im trying to print one api using curl. but so far i wasnt able to get it to work. maybe you guys can help me. the website uses api user and pass both can be viewed in the code i made so far. what this does is it gets the $original_url and gives us a preview based on the template_id which is 20016. you can read the documentation here https://support.dudamobile.com/API/API-Use-Cases/Multiscreen-White-Label-Setup

```
$original_url = "http://rsportugal.org/index.html";
$data = array("template_id"=>"20016","url"=>$original_url);    
$data = json_encode($data);

define("API_USER","...");
define("API_PASS","...");

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.dudamobile.com/api/sites/multiscreen/templates');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, API_USER.':'.API_PASS);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");    

$output = curl_exec($ch);

if(curl_errno($ch)) {
    die('Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch));
}   
$output = json_decode($output);

curl_close($ch);

return $output->site_name;
```

hopefully you guys can help me

Comment: What is the issue? It doesn't work ***how***? What is returned? What is expected?

Comment: your suppost to get a preview of the $original url in a mobile version . heres the documentation https://support.dudamobile.com/API/API-Use-Cases/Multiscreen-White-Label-Setup

Comment: Try printing out without JSON decoding. It could be the JSON is malformed. Further, you may find it easier to use this CURL wrapper: http://semlabs.co.uk/journal/object-oriented-curl-class-with-multi-threading

Comment: What the error reporting says `ini_set("display_errors",1); error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: Trying to get property of non-object in line 32 "return $output->site_name;"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you want to do a http POST on an url that doesn't support POST.

If you want to get 20016 template data, you have to do so :

```
$templateId = 20016;

define("API_USER","..."); 
define("API_PASS","...");

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.dudamobile.com/api/sites/multiscreen/templates/' . $templateId);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, API_USER.':'.API_PASS);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($data));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");    

$output = curl_exec($ch);

if(curl_errno($ch)) {
    die('Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch));
}   
$output = json_decode($output);

print_r($output);

curl_close($ch);
```

Full API documentation here => [Duda mobile api Doc](https://support.dudamobile.com/API/REST-Resources/Multiscreen-Site)

Comment: @Paul Giragossian  Thank you for suggestion.